# How to use JavaScript with CHtml button() on a Yii page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, yii, renderpartial

I'm trying to use JavaScript in my page. My JavaScript code is:

```
function edit(){
  alert("test"); 
  return document.getElementById("confirm").value="";
}
```

Calling this, by `onclick` function

```
<?php echo CHtml::button("Edit",array('title'=>"Edit",'onclick'=>'js:edit();')); ?>
```

both where in same page and confirmation.php

Answer (score 4):

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('register_script_name', "
    $('#editButton').click(function(){
       alert('edit');
       return false;
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);

<?php echo CHtml::button("Edit",array('title'=>"Edit",'id'=>"editButton")); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Odil Sattorov..
im learning yii now only.. here in my case, the 'register_script_name' is the javascript file ??

Comment: No this is a unique identifier of the script. You can put any name there.

Comment: hi odil sattorov, still which is not working for me, i dont know where i did mistake.. what else i need to add.. this script is on the page, i didnt make it as a file. kindly help me

Comment: @sher Not working is big thing, Open the firebug and tell the error.

Comment: If you are using Firefox get [firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=firebug&appver=&platform=) and open it and reload the page and you should see error, give us the error can help us to help you

Comment: i got the following warning,
Use of globalStorage is deprecated. Please use localStorage instead.
Use of attributes' nodeName attribute is deprecated. Use name instead.
Use of attributes' nodeValue attribute is deprecated. Use value instead.

Comment: Also i have the report no script on the page.. but i have the script in the page

Comment: The warning that u gave has nothing to do with the script. The warning  must belong to something else(some other script)

Answer (score 1):

Set an ID for your button:

```
<?php echo CHtml::button("Edit",array('title'=>"Edit",'id'=>'myButton')); ?>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
        alert("test");
        document.getElementById("confirm").value = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you can just remove the `js:` part from your code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::button("Edit",array('title'=>"Edit",'onclick'=>'edit()')); ?>
```

Comment: Thx Samuel liew,
not working bro.. actually my code was working, later i renderPartial from another page, thn only javascript not calling, except this all working

Comment: still not working, am i need to include anything to make javascript to work. no reaction is taken